# glibc-debuginfo ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glibc

I am unable to find the compatible version of **glibc-debuginfo-2.17-222.el7.ppc64le.rpm** and **glibc-debuginfo-common-2.17-222.el7.ppc64le.rpm** for my *ubuntu version 20.04 x86_64* architecture.
please guide me with this...

Comment: Could you explain why you want RHEL or CentOS packages on Ubuntu? Are you following a guide of some sort, and if so, which one?

Comment: yes i am following this (https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/linux/articles/introducing-linux-splat/) tutorial to get lock time values of a thread